# Javascript/jQuery: How to extract attribute/property from an HTML string (value of event.target)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

TLDR: I have a string that's in HTML format and I want to extract some text from it.

example html string (the actual HTML string I'm parsing is the value of event.target)

```
<div class="dclass">
    <div class="dclass1 container">
        <p class="pclass11 my-classes-here">text</p>
        <img class="img-generic-class another-img-class" alt="my-alt-text1" src="my-img-source-here1">
    </div>
    <div class="dclass2 container">
        <p class="pclass21 my-classes-here">text</p>
        <img class="img-generic-class another-img-class" alt="my-alt-text2" src="my-img-source-here2">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to I retrieve the string "my-alt-text2"? I thought of:

- converting to DOM but unsure to do it
- I tried $.parseHTML on the HTML string (on the actual string I'm working on and not the example string. The actual string is also a lot more complicated that the example) and it returned a null

Thanks

Comment: `$(".img-class2").attr("alt");` isnt the selector for the second image is `.dclass2  .img-generic-class another-img-class`..?and which `event.target` you refer to? is there any event the image involved with?

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '<div><img class="img-class2" src="#" alt="Your alt here!"></div>'; //Your html string

var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = html;

console.log(tmpDiv.querySelector('.img-class2').getAttribute('alt'));
```